# Delta Table / Athena And Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-athena, delta-lake

I have my delta table, which can be read from Athena.

[image]

When I try to get the data through a query from spark I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 80.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 80.0 (TID 449, ip-172-31-22-178.ec2.internal, executor 2): java.lang.RuntimeException: s3://<path>/BDA/DELTA/CLIENTE/_symlink_format_manifest/PERIODO=202001/manifest is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [117, 101, 116, 10]
```

[image]

[image]

if I do that same query in athena, there are no problems

[image]

Comment: this might help https://giters.com/delta-io/delta/issues/706 ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your delta file was already created with a manifest to be read in athena now if you want to read it with spark, it has to be this way

%sql
select * from delta.`s3://path/tabla/` limit